# How to get the real shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: c, shortest-path, dijkstra

I want to find the shortest path between two pixels of a binary matrix. The elements which are equal to 0 indicate a passable node, while 1s indicate an obstacle.
I tried to solve the problem by implementing a C version of the Dijkstra's algorithm, but the path I obtained is not what I expected. Instead of having a straight line between the two pixels, I got several segments. The following images show some examples:

[image: Obtained path vs expected path]

[image]

This is the pseudocode of the algorithm I implemented: ([I took it from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode)):

```
function Dijkstra(Graph, source):

    create a empty list of nodes L          // the list will contains all the element of the matrix qual to 0. (1s are bostavles)

    for each node n:            
        weights[n] ← INFINITY                 
        prev[n] ← UNDEFINED                
        add n to L

    weights[source] ← 0
  
    while L is not empty:
        c ← node in L with min weights[c]
                                       
        remove c from L                     // the current node will be removed from the L list
        
        for each neighbor v of c:           // only v that are still in L
            alt ← weights[c] + length(c, v)  // calculate the new weights for the neighbor 
                if alt < dist[v]:              
                    weights[v] ← alt
                    prev[v] ← c

return weights[], prev[]
```

In my case `length(c, v)` is equal to `sqrt(2)` for the neighbor along the diagonals `1` otherwise as shown in the picture.
[image]

How can I obtain the real shortest path and not an approximation of it?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that it does not work when you are working with pseudocode? Try to post real code and then it can be discussed.

Comment: Dijkstra's (and other path-finding) algorithms can only follow the paths that you give it. If you connect only the eight adjacent pixels, you'll get paths that are verticall, hirizontal and 45°-diagonal only. The problem is not with the algorithm, but with how you model your "playing field".

Comment: To illustrate what I've said above: A possible graph to work with [might look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hffg2.png), where the weight of each edge is the actual length of the line. If you have only a few obstacles, the graph should be much sparser that what you have. If you have many obstacles, it will not be trivial to construct the graph.

Comment: If your obstacles are aligned to each other, you could [compress your coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29532057/2979617) and adapt the weight of each moves to the actual extent of the compressed "pixel".